# Area and volumes of solids formed by revolution of curve

Tags: area

For finding the volume of a solid ( eg. Sphere ) we devide it into various strips which somehow look like a frustum of cone. And we find the area of this infinitesimal frustum area assuming upper and lower radius are almost equal and slant height equal rdx ( x is polar angle ).
My question is that here we are assuming Both radii almost equal and the shape like a frustum because actually this infinitesimal ring is not frustum of cone. ( Because cone had straight part from on going from bottom to top, but it has somehow curved path ) So as I think that these two assumption will lead to difference in actual area and calculated area of this strip. Though we can neglect it for a single strip but when summed over infinite strips  that may lead to a finite difference in calculated and actual area and we may not get exact answer. Please solve my query in easy language . I am just a school student .